# How do I match by all objects in an array of objects in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get documents like below with match from Elasticsearch.

```json
{
  "configurationId": "dp4wb8kpw4k1s2z",
  "type": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "text": "car",
      "rank": 1
    },
    {
      "text": "ship",
      "rank": 2
    }
  ],
  "date": "2021-07-08"
}
```

But I want a match on all objects in the items array and I want to get documents with this match.  For example, the text value of the object with a rank value of 1 in the items array should definitely be "car", and the text value of the object with a rank value of 2 in the array should definitely be "ship".

How do I write a query in Elasticsearch for this?

Comment: can you please share some sample index data, and expected search result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested object instead of array of object in Elasticsearch.

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type
> instead of the object data type.

for more information check Elasticsearch official documentation about arrays here and for Nested object [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

After changing your mapping to nested object you will be able to query like this:

Query:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "items.text": "car" }},
            { "match": { "items.rank": 1 }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```